# MS ACCESS 2016 Multiple Joins Syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I write the followin SQL Query in MS ACCESS 2016 syntax?

```
SELECT 
    ticket.ticket_id,  
    a1.attr_val AS attr_val1,
    a2.attr_val AS attr_val2,
    a3.attr_val AS attr_val3
FROM ticket
    LEFT JOIN attr a1 ON ticket.ticket_id=a1.ticket_id AND a1.attr_type=1
    LEFT JOIN attr a2 ON ticket.ticket_id=a2.ticket_id AND a2.attr_type=2
    LEFT JOIN attr a3 ON ticket.ticket_id=a3.ticket_id AND a3.attr_type=3
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 3):

MS Access has these [weird requirements about parentheses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209493%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

> **Join expression not supported. (Error 3296)**
>
> Possible causes:
>
> - Your SQL statement contains multiple joins in which the results of the query can differ, depending on the order in which the joins are performed. You may want to create a separate query to perform the first join, and then include that query in your SQL statement.
> - The `ON` statement in your `JOIN` operation is incomplete or contains too many tables. You may want to put your `ON` expression in a `WHERE` clause.

The solutions suggested in the above quote are not always appropriate (e.g. using the `WHERE` clause is not an option for `LEFT JOIN` conditions).

#### How to solve:

- Group joins in parentheses such that each join expression only has one join in it;
- Enclose the `ON` expression with parentheses;

#### SQL:

```
SELECT 
    ticket.ticket_id,  
    a1.attr_val AS attr_val1,
    a2.attr_val AS attr_val2,
    a3.attr_val AS attr_val3
FROM ((ticket
    LEFT JOIN attr AS a1 ON (ticket.ticket_id=a1.ticket_id AND a1.attr_type=1))
    LEFT JOIN attr AS a2 ON (ticket.ticket_id=a2.ticket_id AND a2.attr_type=2))
    LEFT JOIN attr AS a3 ON (ticket.ticket_id=a3.ticket_id AND a3.attr_type=3)
```

Comment: it looks like it doesnt like the "AS" statement

Comment: when I omit the "AS" it says something like "expression join is not supported"

Comment: I updated my answer after having reproduced the tables in a MS Access database myself: you need to wrap the whole `ON` condition in a pair of parenthesis. The query as it is now in my answer should work: it works for me.